# Displaying RSS or ATOM content in ASP.NET ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss, atom-feed

I am having some trouble pulling RSS off of blogger page and publishing it on my own site. I am using SyndicationFeed to pull the data down and parse it. I am able to accomplish this but not without quite a bit of code.

I feel like there should be a while of doing this in a few lines of code and bind that to the ListView.

Can anyone point me at a 'really simple' way to pull rss or atom feed off of another site and bind its contents into a ListView control on my page, including the content of each item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This blog post describes an easy way using `XmlDataSource` in ASP.NET:

- [ASP.NET 3.5 ListView and DataPager : Making RSS Reader](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2009/04/20/asp-net-3-5-listview-and-datapager-making-rss-reader.aspx)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks! That worked for RSS only. Although  I was able to modify it for Atom.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [ASP.NET RSS Toolkit](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Texture.html)